# UITabBarController, UINavigationController from another NIB file

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I spent several hours trying to load subclassed `UINavigationController` from another NIB while taping a `tabBarItem`. Does anyone have any idea, how to do it correctly?

The latest test:

MainWindow.xib - `UITabBarController` with 4 tabs, one is named News and is set to "Navigation Controller". While News tab is selected - class identity: `NewsNavigationController`, NIB Name: NewsView.

View loaded from NewsView appeared in the Window

Running this variant leads to:

> Loading 123209 stack frames... (16%) and counting :)   Removing class
>   identity ends with crash: *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key newsTableViewController.'

It's clear that Class indentity IS the way to go, but why does it not work for me?

Comment: How did you build your NewsView nib? It will help for better understanding of the crash

Comment: Hello,
the NewsView is not involved in the crash in any way imho. But to answer your question:
File's owner is NewsNavigationController (subclass of UINavigationController).

The crash occurs somewhere very deep inside of